# Is it safe to use Redis pool inside kafka streams?

Tags: java, redis, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So, the question is about safety to use external state storage inside stream functions like filter, map and etc.

Is it ok to do something like this:

```
JedisPool pool = ...;
KStream stream = ...;
stream.map((k, v) -> {
    JedisClient client = pool.getResource();
    ....
    client.close();
});
...
KafkaStreams streams = ...;
```

Can it cause errors because of using single pool inside multiple streaming tasks?
In apache flink i can use `Rich*Function<>` where i can configure connection pool to any storage only once inside `open` method. In apache spark i also can configure global connections. Do i need to do the same using kafka streams or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An equivalent to `Rich*Function` would be to use a `transform()` instead of `map()` that allows you to `init()` and `close()` a `Transformer`.

Your approach should work, too, even if you might want to `try-catch` to ensure `close()` is executed. However, it's not a recommended pattern.

Depending on your use case, it might be better to load the data from Redis into a Kafka topic (not sure if there is an Redis connector) and load the data into a KTable. Instead of a `map()` or `transform()` you would do a stream-table join.

Comment: Thank you! Probably, transform is exactly what i need.
In my case i need to store specific data into cache and at first glance i don't see a possibility for using KTable

Answer (score -1):

Redis is not recommended for production with Spring Cloud Stream - the binder is not fully functional and message loss is possible.